# Regex - Non greedy Text between two strings

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex that gets text between two characters.  Example below:

```
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
    xyz
/***/ }),
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
    abc
/***/ }),
```

The result I want is "xyz" and "abc".

Here is the regex I came up with but it only sees 1 result..

```
(\/\*\*\*\/ \(function\(module, exports\) \{)(.*)[\s\S]*\/\*\*\*\/ }\),
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: How reliable is `/***/ (function(module, exports) {\n    ` and `\n/***/ }),\n`?

Comment: I results i am looking for are guaranteed to be between /***/ (function(module, exports) { and /***/ }),

Comment: For clarity (since you found the answer yourself), the term you are looking for is "lazy match". In regex, all multi-selectors are greedy by default. Adding a ? after it like .*? or .{1,7}? will match the minimum viable piece to make a positive match.

Answer (score 0):

As a first guess

```
\(function\(module\,\ exports\)\ \{\s*([^\n]+)\s*\/\*
```

Here is the output https://regex101.com/r/tfQfWo/1

--

```
\(function\(module\,\ *exports\)\ *\{\s*([^\n]+)\s*\/\*
```

Here is the output https://regex101.com/r/tfQfWo/3

Comment: That works nicely.  I updated it to use:
\/\*\*\*\/ \(function\(module\,\ exports\)\ \{\s*([^\n]+)\s*\/\*\*\*\/ }\)\,

This looks at the complete pattern.  How do I make it ignore the spaces between the pattern?

Example function(module,export)....

Comment: @user7886649 That is why I asked how reliable the fixed pieces were. Are there any other parts that can vary?

Comment: The regex i modified it to does not seem to be captured correctly when I post it here.  Based on your original regex, can you show me how to ignore spaces in the pattern

Comment: Just the spaces in the pattern.  SOrry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: works like a charm.  Now i can spend some time understanding it.  You are a champ!

Comment: Will this regex work if the text i am looking for is embedded within other text?

Comment: @user7886649 I would have to see a sample. Again, it's about what's variant and fixed.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/XVluNK/2

Here is a link to the source text.

Results should be the fake functions: doSomething, doSomethingElse, doYetAnotherThing...

Answer (score 0):

```
(?s)\/\*\*\*\/\s\(function\(module,\ exports\)\s\{(.*?)\}\)\,
```

Figured out the solution.  THe above works.